# Disable the responsive of the site in pestrashop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on the this site http://www.alloccasions-florist.co.uk/.

I already disable the option of responsive from admin panel but no effect on the site, i have removed all the media screen css property from the css file still  there is no effect. can anyone help me what should i do for this?

How I disable the responsive of that website?

Answer (score 0):

You have deal with media queries. As a example go to http://www.alloccasions-florist.co.uk/themes/default-bootstrap/css/global.css and delete content start with @media. But be careful very time. Good to backup your css and delete content one at the time and check it change the frontend look

Comment: actually i did that but it will mess the desktop version as well

Comment: '@media (min-width: 1200px) {' don't delete this part. But make sure to remove only @media (min-width: 1200px) { snippet and related '}' and let me know if you face issue